# Getting pip dependency error following TFX tutorial

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip, tfx

I'm trying to follow the Tensorflow Extended tutorial from the official website:
https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/tutorials/tfx/components_keras

When I try executing the line

```
pip install -q -U --use-feature=2020-resolver tfx
```

I get the following error:

[image]

I haven't been able to find anything online - any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is due to dependency mismatch. Use virtual environment to get rid of such kind of problems.

```
#Create virtual environment named env
python -m venv env

#Activate the environment
source env/bin/activate

#Now install packages you need using pip
pip install -q -U --use-feature=2020-resolver tfx
```

These instructions are for Linux OS. If you are using windows let me know. Will help you with that.

Comment: Is this helpful to you?

Comment: Can you upvote the solution if it's helpful?

Answer (score 0):

Please replace the --use-feature flag with --use-deprecated=legacy-resolver to work around the dependency error.

Answer (score 0):

There is a TFX tutorial recently published by [Adaltas](https://www.adaltas.com/en/) which might help you to get your environment up and running. It is based on Miniconda: https://www.adaltas.com/en/2021/03/05/tfx-overview/. Here is an extract:

```
$ conda --version
conda 4.9.1
$ conda create --name env_tfx python=3.7
$ conda activate env_tfx
(env_tfx)$ pip install tensorflow==2.3.0  
(env_tfx)$ pip install tfx==0.24.1
(env_tfx)$ pip install notebook
```